# Some PC's on domain can login to ASP.NET using identity some can not

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis, webforms

I am using standard .net framework 4.7.2 with identity for authentication, no changes have been made to the standard code however when I publish to IIS on a windows 2012 R2 server some users can login and some can't. The application is hitting the Database because if the incorrect credentials are used the validation returns invalid login credentials but when the correct details are used it just reloads the login page without logging in the user. this is only for certain PC's. Some of the PC's have problems and then without any changes they can suddenly login later in the day.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening.

On the authentication on the app pool( Anonymous, web forms amd windows authentication are enabled the rest are disabled).

Comment: Do you mean you have enabled both windows auth and identity for your asp.net web form application? Do you used the mixed auth package in your web application? Which error message you have faced for couldn't login in??

Comment: No the application is set up to use a database where only users created on the app can use that account to login in. The types of Authentication I mentioned are how the IIS is configured. 
There is no error message everything works as designed but for some users when they try to login it just spins them back to the login page without actually logging them in

Comment: the authentication is base on some cookies - check if the browsers allowed to place cookies, check if you have setup them correctly on web.config

Comment: The weird things is that the user will login successfully but when they log out and try to log back in sometimes it doesn't allow them to and just keeps reloading the login page. So i doubt it is a browser problem, about the web config can you send me an example of what you consider to be a correct setup

Comment: You could try to use remote debug to remote debug the identity related codes to check how it generate the token and how it verify the token. More details about how to remote debug it ,you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2019).

Comment: It seemed to be an issue on the IIS because every time I restart IIS it allows users to login for a while then it stops allow it. I’ve set the website to recycle on a more regular basis and that seems to be working. I haven’t encountered any problems yet using this method